# type erasure in a poly function, scala

Tags: scala, types, dictionary, shapeless, hlist

So I wanted to make a map function over a `HList`, but I need to check for some conditions inside the applying function. Smth like:

```
object test extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[L <: HList](implicit head: ops.hlist.IsHCons[L]) = 
    at[L](t => {
        if(true) t.head else false //here some condition    
    })
}
```

As the result, we loose all information about `type` of `t.head` element; btw if we build "clean" function:

```
object test extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[L <: HList](implicit head: ops.hlist.IsHCons[L]) = 
    at[L](t => t.head)
}
```

Then, obviously, it's all ok.

So the question is: how to deal with it, and to make such sort of function (if it's possible) or I should search another way? Why here can be type erasure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't type erasure or anything tricky to do with Shapeless—it's just that the inferred type of a conditional expression is the least upper bound of the type of the two branches, and in this case that's `Any`. You can see the same thing happen with a plain old polymorphic method:

```
scala> def foo[A](a: A) = if (true) a else false
foo: [A](a: A)Any
```

As a side note, it would be a little more elegant (and idiomatic) to match on the structure of the `HList` instead of requiring an instance of the `IsHCons` type class:

```
object test extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[H, T <: HList] = at[H :: T](_.head)
}
```

This does exactly the same thing as your "clean" example.

Comment: oh, I see, and if I write smth like: `at[L](if(true) t => t.head else t => false)` I will get `Any` ... It is again cause of all function type?

Hm so as I thought...
Thx for a cool note about `head` usage, btw, it would be cool not to pass all other implicits (for map, flat map, diff custom helpers, etc...)  :D

Comment: Ophh I understood completely! thx, now it is all clear for me.